# nifi getFile not picking file regex not working

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

i am using following as path filter => `.*\/(?i)(logs|testing_do_not_delete)\/.*`

i just want to read files from above mentioned 2 folders.

Nifi is not reading any files. not from any folder. I have 4 folders

```
logs
log123
testing_do_not_delete
testing_do_not_delete_bkp
```

when i remove path filter, processor reads file from all 4 folders.

Comment: Are you sure the method you are using accepts a regex, and not  a  glob pattern?

Comment: sure, when i give glob pattern. I am getting error as => not a valid java regex.

Comment: Then, try `(?i)^(?:.*/)?(?:logs|testing_do_not_delete)(?:/.*)?$`

Comment: it worked, can you please post it as answer? i can then mark this as answered. thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to match the whole string and make sure that if there is a word you search for it is between either the start/end of string or slashes.

You may use

```
(?i)^(?:.*/)?(?:logs|testing_do_not_delete)(?:/.*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mFljAi/1).

**Details**

- `(?i)` - case insensitive mode on
- `^` - start of string
- `(?:.*/)?` - an optional sequence (`(?:...)?`) of any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible (`.*`),  followed with a `/` char
- `(?:logs|testing_do_not_delete)` - a non-capturing group matching either `logs` or `testing_do_not_delete`
- `(?:/.*)?` - an optional sequence of any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, followed with a `/` char
- `$` - end of string.